# Socket flags how to use them with Python

Tags: python, sockets

Hello I am trying to figure out how to send FIN/ACK flags using pythons socket module.

I have not been able to find the info I needed on this

this is the concept I am looking at

```
socket.send(data, flags="FA")
```

Obviously not correct

I do not wish to use scapy for this, so I appreciate advise using pythons socket module. Any advice is greatly appreciated

Thanks for your help.

*cheers

Comment: User-mode code never directly sends `FIN` or `ACK` packets (or `SYN` packets, for that matter)—that's all handled by the TCP stack inside the kernel.  User code only indirectly sends such packets by asking the OS to do so using the system calls `send(2)`, `recv(2)`, `shutdown(2)`, and `close(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to let the other party know that you're closing the connection, you can use

```
# s is a socket.socket object
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
s.close()
```

---

The `flags` argument to `send` has a different meaning, and may be used to send the `MSG_OOB` and `MSG_DONTROUTE` flags - see `man send` for the list.

Those flags would be used by doing:

```
s.send(data, flags=socket.MSG_OOB | socket.MSG_DONTROUTE)
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help! Just to note s.send(data, socket.MSG_OOB | socket.MSG_DONTROUTE) worked for me *cheers